# Is there a way to add Block IDs to CanPlaceOn and CanDestroy-Tags using Bukkit?

Tags: java, server, minecraft, bukkit

I want to make a plugin which allows the user to add Block IDs to the CanPlaceOn or CanDestroy Tag of an item or a block. I know that this also can be achieved with the /give command but many players of my server are absolutely not familiar with commands. Therefore I tried to make a command where a gui pops up and you can place blocks into a certain slot to add them to the item which is being "edited" (to canplaceon or canbreak).

I already setup the Gui and everything else and now I am stuck with the problem of not being able to modify the NBT Tags with bukkit. There is no way to do this with bukkit and I saw some answers using NMS (Im ok with mns solutions, if they work!) but they seem to be outdated and no longer working on my 1.17.1 Spigot server. My Method to add a block ID currently looks like this:

```
public void addBlockToCanPlaceOn(ItemStack item, Material block){

     // Add the block-ID of 'block' to the CanPlaceOnTag of 'item'

}
```

Does someone have an idea for adding Block IDs to the CanPlaceOn/CanDestroy-Tag of an item?

Answer (score 0):

Block IDs have been deprecated by Mojang and a lot of functions to get the IDs of blocks have been replaced with their material name alternatives. (I'm a legacy developer and it sucks to see but it doesn't matter much). This may be part of your troubles.

Had you seen this: https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/adding-canplaceon-nbttag-via-plugin.247846/ post on SpigotMC? Seems like they had & fixed this issue with some support (And they posted their code at the second bottom post).